# Not able to attch the source in Spring Source Tool Suite

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

I have created one project in STS where we are using Hibernate 3 and other FW.
In my IDE I have already selected the option as Windows->Prefrence->Maven->Download Artifact Source -> OK

after that all the jar etc downloaded for project. but the Problem is when i am clicking to any hibernate Class it is not able to locate the souce code file.

and showing message as "The Source attachment doesnt contain source for for the file "

So please help me out to attach the Source Code In STS??

Comment: Is the source file downloaded in you local maven repository? Default: `<USER>/.m2/repository`